# Create array with the length based on a number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this var `let number = 3`

I'd like to create an array with the length based on the number listed above, But the content should be a string like this:

`"item {index of item in array}",`

so my array should look like this: `let array = ['item 0', 'item 1', 'item 2']`

Righ now I have this code:

```
let number = 2
let array = Array.from(Array(number).keys())
// outcome --> [ 0 , 1 ]
```

But I don't know how to add the strings in a correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.from()` accepts a callback, and you can use it to create the items.

```js
const number = 2

const array = Array.from(Array(number).keys(), k => `item ${k}`)

console.log(array)
```

In addition, you can use the index (`i`) of the item as the counter.

```js
const number = 2

const array = Array.from(Array(number), (_, i) => `item ${i}`)

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution

```
let arr = [...Array(number).keys()].map(x=>`item ${x}`);
```

or

```
let arr = [...Array(number)].map((y, x)=>`item ${x}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
let number = 2;
let array = Array(number).fill().map((ele, i) => `item ${i}`);
```